# Differences between Logstash and Fluentd

Tags: logging, logstash, fluentd

What are the major differences between Logstash and Fluentd?

What I know so far is:

**Both:**
  - Open Source
  - Available on Linux and Windows
  - Data/log collectors

**Logstash:**
  - Centralized repo for plugins
  - Small fixed queue size (often need Redis to manage)
  - More memory intensive (~120 MB)
  - Commonly apart of the ELK stack

**Fluentd:**
  - Decentralized repo for plugins
  - Built-in, dynamic queue management (but makes setup more complicated)
  - Less memory intensive (~30-40 MB)

Source: https://logz.io/blog/fluentd-logstash/

Are there any major differences that I, or this article, missed that are worth mentioning?